# AMP on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, amp-html

I am new to AMP and RoR. Is there any Gem that will help to include AMP enabled pages in Ruby on rails(ERB Template and rails version is 5.x.x).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using this gem: https://github.com/takafumir/rails_amp

It helps a lot, but still you need to take care of css and html for AMP. There is no auto conversion, AFAIK.